# Google Oauth By url For youtube api

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api

I am creating a app to test Subscription Insert method . In the app i like to authenticate from url . Like i put google login page in webview . I heard a method that we can access token from url . I don't know how i can get it . please tell me the process and guide me how i can achieve it .

```
package com.google.api.client.auth.oauth;

import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.util.Beta;
import com.google.api.client.util.Key;

@Beta
public class OAuthAuthorizeTemporaryTokenUrl
extends GenericUrl {
    @Key(value="oauth_token")
    public String temporaryToken;

    public OAuthAuthorizeTemporaryTokenUrl(String string) {
        super(string);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

kindly refer to this site: [Obtaining authorization credentials](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application)

it is the last part of the URL:
[see example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObYwq.png)

Comment: I asked authorization credentials from url . do u have any reference to gain from url ?

Comment: just search the video on youtube that you would like to gain reference with

Comment: have you seen the picture? It's below the tab. :) you can also use this video as guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a4NT5iBFuZs

Comment: yes, In the video there is no such a info about authentication